# Will all binary codes stay in memory during runtime?

Tags: operating-system, executable

Let's say if I execute a binary:

> ./a.out

Then will all the code in a.out be loaded into memory every time ? What if this binary is too large (Say, several GB) while process address space only have 4GB?

The reason I'm asking this is because I found a saying that code bloating will degrade performance in a virtual memory based system. However, I never see such a case where program need to page the code from disk. When can this situation happen?

Comment: You should find and read some good descriptions of virtual memory, especially the parts about demand paging. The short answer is "no". On most modern systems, a program starts with none of it's executable loaded in memory, and specific pages are only loaded as they are referenced by the code as it executes. There are some older systems (e.g. DOS) where the full program was loaded at the start, though, and some embedded platforms may still do something like that.

Comment: @twalberg Thanks. Now I understood that application codes are under demand paging in Linux. But how about Linux OS code segment? Does it use demand paging or not? (I read ULK and it says that OS code stays at first few MB in memory so the answer is no?)

Comment: Correct. There are certain parts of especially the operating system kernel that are loaded at boot time and never paged out (imagine what would happen if the code that handles paging stuff in and out were not present in memory - how would it load itself?). Linux provides facilities for applications to request that certain portions of their code never be paged out as well - bypassing the demand paging mechanism - but those facilities need to be used carefully, as trying to keep everything locked in memory leaves less room for the rest of the system to run optimally...